# c#. App.exe.config does is not used

Tags: c#, settings, application-settings

I have deployed an app that downloads from a web server. This is a normal desktop app installed using a msi produced by Visual Studio setup project. The address of the server is stored in app.exe.config as an application setting. Later, I change the address in app.exe.config using notepad, but the app is still using the old web address. In fact, I tried deleting the app.exe.config and the app still managed to get the old web address?????

Can someone explain what is happening.

Sorry if it confused some people. The settings are managed using the C# project's properties -> Settings page. The project is called updatesdownloader and the actual file I edit is updatesdownloader.exe.config which is in the same folder as the exe.

The code I used to read the server address string is:

Server updateServer = new Server(new Uri(UpdatesDownloader.Properties.Settings.Default.Server));

Comment: please show the code in your application which reads the configs from such config file

Answer (score 1):

Where is the file that you are changing?  Is the setting a user setting or an application setting?

You may want to look for your settings in the %AppData% or %ProgramData% folders on the user's machines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to us `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection` for a custom section that contains your settings.

[Check this for an example](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2006/11/13/app-config-and-custom-configuration-sections.aspx) on how to create a custom section

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the address is not hard-coded in the app itself? I would be sure that if you made reference to a URL using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeUrl"];` and attempted to go there, it would fail if the file did not exist.